# Can't compile iOS-App with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Trying to compile an iOS Build shows the following error message:

```
Could not find 'Xamarin.iOS'
```

The setting "Deployment Target" on the page "iOS Application"  shows this message:

```
Unable to retrieve iOS SDK information from Xamarin Mac Agent server.
```

The setting "iOS Bundle Signing" in the project properties shows the following message:

```
Failed to obtain Profile information from the build server.
Please, check the connectivity with the Mac build host
```

Visual Studio is successfully connected to a Mac with XCode 8.1. The Xamarin Mac Agent on Windows shows the Mac with a valid "chain" symbol. The "Device Log" on Windows shows all messages from an iPad connected to the Mac, so the connection to the Mac works.

Rebooting all systems had no effect. 
Creating an iPad App with Xcode alone works flawless, it runs perfectly on the iPad using the provisioning profile from Xcode.

Version information:

- Windows 10.0.10586
- macOS 10.12.1
- Visual Studio Community 2015 (Windows) Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Xamarin Studio Community (Mac)  Version 6.1.2 (build 44)
- XCode 8.1 (8B62)

Comment: try updating the system clock:http://kevinkallberg.com/blog/post/2014/01/28/XamariniOS-Error-Failed-to-obtain-information-about-the-remotes-profile-files-Unable-to-check-SDK-status

Comment: Both clocks are in sync, same date and time.

Comment: Solution found: 
Reinstalling Xamarin Studio on the Mac helped. 
The installation forced me to install some components manually. After that, I installed Xamarin Studio a second time, and then it all worked fine.